# Effective ways to display confusion matrices from different predictors in an academic publication?

Tags: matrix, predictor, confusion-matrix

I want to display the results of two different predictors' performance on a dataset. I have a confusion matrix for each of the predictors' results on the test cases. I want to present these confusion matrices in an academic publication (focusing on the false positives difference between the two). These matrices are 2x2.

Which options are best suited for presenting the two confusion matrix information?

1. As a subfigure along with the dataset trajectory figure?
2. Within the caption of the dataset trajectory figure?
3. Two matrices in the equation environment in the discussion of the results?
4. As a list of numbers within a sentence in the discussion?